# Is there a way to dynamically switch between vw and vh (viewport width/height) using Javascript/css?

Tags: css, dynamic, viewport-units

I'm writing a responsive design, and using vw for font sizes works wonderfully.  Problem is vmax is not supported in webkit yet, so the question becomes:

Is there a way to dynamically switch font rendering sizes from using vw to using vh for when the client screen is in a narrow portrait mode (such as iphone 5 portrait)?

I tried to 'cheat' by setting the viewport minimum-width but this appears to not work.  The actual width of the screen always seems to supersede.

Comment: I'm not sure, will `@media (min-aspect-ratio:1)` and alike help?

Comment: I can use media queries to determine the aspect/window dimensions and have it swith css on the fly.  I think it may be the only thing i can do. I guess i was hoping for a more simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd feature test it with a tool like Modernizr. Write crossbrowser CSS by default and enhance it for modern browsers by using `.my-text.vmax { font-size: ... }`.

Comment: I don't understand how that works.  Where is the vw value and where is the max viewport width to emulate?